# How to do deep copy of NHibernate Objects?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, object, deep-copy

I am trying to do a deep copy of a NHibernate object (proxy wrapper). I want to do a copy of lazily loaded things also, except the `Id` of each inner object of the parent object, as it should be generated when I save the new object which is the result of deep copy.

I have tried to use serialization and also tried using AutoMapper (I know, its not meant for this, just gave it a try). Both didn't yield what I want.

I am thinking of manually copying each and every property as the last option, if there is no better way to do it.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299932/deep-copy-entity-with-nhibernate), but it didn't address what I wanted, considering I was reluctant to do the copy manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to have more customizations done as we went on cloning the classes.

So, in our case manual clone was the way to go (even though I was hoping for a better solution).

Answer (score 0):

we're using [Copyable](http://ox.no/software/copyable) to clone objects (deep clones). [Here](http://ox.no/posts/extension-methods-for-copying-or-cloning-objects) you can find an article describing Copyable. It provides extension methods (for 'object') that allow to clone object graphs and generally works very well for us. HTH.